# Node router for marketplace routes

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, node.js, ecmascript-6, url-routing

After cleaning up & some refactoring, one module of my code became like below. 
However, I'm feeling like there's still some unnecessary redundancy, and it can be improved further and look neater.

But I can't come up with exactly how to do it.

```
'use strict';

// === showing the execution context ==============

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const moment = require("moment");
const momentDurationSetup = require("moment-duration-format");
const DB = require('./DBOperator');
const _ = require('lodash');

const Promise = require("bluebird");
const request = require('superagent-bluebird-promise');

const utils = require('../utils');


// ========== main concern area ===============

function realTime(queryFunction, payload, req, res, next) {
    queryFunction((err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            next();
        } else {
            res.json({data: _.get(results[0].rows[0], payload, -1)});
        }
    });
}

router.get('/online-buyer-count', utils.mcache(15), (req, res, next) => {
    realTime(DB.onlinebuyerNumQuery, 'onlinebuyerNum', req, res, next);
});

router.get('/offline-buyer-count', utils.mcache(15), (req, res, next) => {
    realTime(DB.offlinebuyerNumQuery, 'offlinebuyerNum', req, res, next);
});

router.get('/online-seller-count', utils.mcache(15), (req, res, next) => {
    realTime(DB.onlinesellerNumQuery, 'onlinesellerNum', req, res, next);
});

router.get('/offline-seller-count', utils.mcache(15), (req, res, next) => {
    realTime(DB.offlinesellerNumQuery, 'offlinesellerNum', req, res, next);
});


/ ===========================

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/120114/sam-onela) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Comment: @samOnela that makes sense. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Partial application

One way to simplify the code is to eliminate the lambda/anonymous functions using [`Function.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to create [Partially applied functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partially_applied_functions). For instance:

> ```
> router.get('/online-buyer-count', utils.mcache(15), (req, res, next) => {
>     realTime(DB.onlinebuyerNumQuery, 'onlinebuyerNum', req, res, next);
> });
> ```

can be simplified to

```
router.get('/online-buyer-count', realTime.bind(null, DB.onlinebuyerNumQuery, 'onlinebuyerNum'));
```

And similarly for the other three routes, which reduces 12 lines to 4.

#### looping over the routes

The redundancy could also be simplified using [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
['online', 'offline'].forEach(mode => { 
    ['buyer', 'seller'].forEach(role => {
        router.get('/'+mode+'-'+role+'-count', realTime.bind(null, DB[mode+role+'NumQuery'], mode+role+'Num'));
    });
});
```

Taking that one step further using more partially-applied functions, the callback function of the inner `forEach` can be pulled out to a separate function:

```
const addRoute = (mode, role) => router.get('/'+mode+'-'+role+'-count', realTime.bind(null, DB[mode+role+'NumQuery'], mode+role+'Num'));
```

And then that function can be made into a partial and used within the nested `forEach`:

```
['online', 'offline'].forEach(mode => ['buyer', 'seller'].forEach(addRoute.bind(null, mode)));
```

So that can reduce those 4 lines to 2. It may be desirable to break those up into multiple lines for readability.

Comment: Thanks a lot. While the first `bind` method is more advanced, the second `forEach` answers my question. It looks more approachable.